# Redemption standalone MAPI Connect to Outlook 365 / O365

Tags: outlook, office365, mapi, outlook-redemption

There is a server with no Outlook client installed and installing it is not an option.
We'd like to access an outlook 365 mailbox with redemption.

I installed the standalone MAPI object(https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42040).
Logging in on the mailbox works, using:
"LogonHostedExchangeMailbox(ThisIsTheAddress@client.com,ThisIsTheAddress@client.com,ThisIsThePassWord)"

After this, the 'LoggedOn' variable on the redemption session returns true.
However, when I try to use 'GetDefaultFolder' I get an error (MAPI_E_VERSION)

I can loop over the stores. But again: when I use 'GetDefaultFolder' on a store, I get the error again.
I just need to access the mails in the inbox and replace them to a subfolder.

I even tried making a profile using MFCMapi, but that didn't seem to work or I did something wrong.
Anyone got this to work? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The latest versions of Exchange explicitly refuse a connection from the standalone version of MAPI.